# Freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezing after first update

Tags: 16.04, boot, kernel

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it works great with the only kernel 4.10.0.-28 preinstalled in the system.

But after the upgrade the laptop is stuck at the initial Ubuntu logo in the purple page (before the login page), if I click any of the `F` keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd>), a dark screen appears and nothing happens.

So after forced shut down, rebooting and using Advanced Option an additional kernel 4.13.0-32 is shown but it's the one freezing the system.

If I proceed choosing the previous kernel the system works fine again.

I searched the web on how to solve the problem for days but up to now any step I tried was useless, I also uploaded Ubuntu from scratch many times.

My laptop is a Acer Aspire Es-1-431-P7vn Intel Pentium Quad Core Processor N3700 @ 1.60 Ghz x 4, Intel Hd Graphics 405 (Braswell), OS type 64-bit, 4 GB DDR3 L Memory, 500 GB HDD.

In `Software & Update` Window, `Additional Drivers` tab this appears:

```
Unknown: Unknown
This device is using an alternative driver
- Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (open source) (THIS IS THE SELECTED OPTION)
- Do not use the device (THIS IS THE UNSELECTED OPTION)
```

Please help!